# RuntimeException: Unabel to instantiate activity ComponentInfo and NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to convert a double type from `EditText`, but I do not seem to understand the right place to write it down.

From what I have research, the error seem to be from the

```
EditText cct = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.curr_credit_text);
```

initialized before `onCreate()` method. However, if I initialize it inside the `onCreate()` method, the other methods cannot access the parsed variable, like so

[image]

Where exactly do I suppose to initialize the variable, so it can then be accessed from other methods?

[image]

I have tried all of the three arrow for the placements, but every time it gives another error.

> Here is the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.user.testapp, PID: 27472
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.testapp/com.example.user.testapp.RevGPAActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2113)
                                                                          at com.example.user.testapp.RevGPAActivity.<init>(RevGPAActivity.java:20)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Initiate variables in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @activesince93 Hello, thanks for replying. I have tried initiating it on the onCreate, however the other method does not recognize the variables. How do i overcome this?

Comment: define/declare the variables at object level, i.e. inside the class but outside the method bodies and initialize those variables in the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 2):

Do initialization like this

```
EditText edt1;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edt1=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.edt_username);
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying, i have done what you wrote, but then there is another same error, but pointing at where I parse the string to double. I already declared it outside the onCreate method, and initiate the parsing inside it. What am I missing?

Comment: in your `calXXX` methods

Answer (score 0):

You must **declare** your variables **outside** the `onCreate()` method and **initialize** them **inside** it.

eg:

```
 private EditText cct;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_rev_gpa);

     cct = (EditText) findViwByid(R.id.curr_creadit_text);
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your variable before onCreate() like this

```
private double CURRENT_CREDIT;
private double FUTURE_CREDIT;
```

and so....

doing this you will declare global varialble which can be acessed in all over the class.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this for each `EditText`:

```
public class RevGPAActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText cct;
    ....

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rev_gpa);

        cct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.current_credit_text);
        ....
    }
}
```

You will be able to access it out of `onCreate()` also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize variable in `onCreate` and get those values when you calculate the `GradPoint()`, you can add a button and call the `GradPoint()` when the button is pressed. Because if you call them in `onCreate`, those functions will be immediately called, you are suppose to call them once the values are entered, right? And if you call them without the values entered, you will get `NumberFormatException` because you are trying to parse an empty string, so you have to be careful while using `Double.parseDouble()` as well. I am writing below a sample code structure to show what I am trying to say here. Hope it helps.

```
EditText edt1;
Button sumbit;
private double CURRENT_CREDIT;
private double FUTURE_CREDIT;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edt1=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.edt_username);
    submit=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.submit);

    ...

    submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
             //Check if all the required values are not empty
            if(!edt1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ...)
                calcGradPoint();
        }
     });
}

void calcGradPoint(){
    CURRENT_CREDIT = Double.parseDouble(ed1.getText().toString());
    ...

}
```